# How to set styles of multiple divs and change hidden value onclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my webpage I have a table with multiple rows. Each rows contains the same items:
 - One title with hidden input
 - One div that functions like a yes-button
 - One div that functions like a no-button

What I'm trying to achieve is when a user clicks on the "yes-button", the style of this DIV changes to "selected" and the style of the "no-button" is removed (set back to normal). Also, the value of the hidden input needs to be set to "yes".

When the user clicks the "no-button", the same as above happens, only this time the other way around (so the opposite) and the hidden input value will be set to "no".

I need javascript to find out the corresponding INPUT and DIV, to prevend that all hidden inputs are set and all DIV's are changed. Javascript needs to find the closest DIV and INPUT.

What I have so far does change the clicked DIV, but doesn't remove the class of the other DIV, nor change the value of the hidden input.

```
<table width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Intern
                    <input type="hidden" name="intern" class="inp-hid">
                </td>
                <td class="profielEditTD">
                    <table>
                    <tr>
                    <td>
                    <div class="YesBTN"></div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    yes
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    &nbsp;
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <div class="NoBTN"></div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    no
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".YesBTN").click(function(){
        $(this).closest(".YesBTN").toggleClass("YesYES");
        $(this).parent(".NoBTN").removeClass("NoYES");
        $(this).parent(".inp-hid").value = "yes"
    });

    $(".NoBTN").click(function(){
        $(this).closest(".NoBTN").toggleClass("NoYES");
        $(this).parent(".YesBTN").removeClass("YesYES");
        $(this).parent(".inp-hid").value = "no"
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Your selector is badly wrong. And you have a problem with assigning value to the text box.

Comment: Thank you, I find out already that it's wrong. Any suggestions on how to fix the value-part?

Answer (score 0):

In your event handlers, `this` will refer to the clicked element; the button. Thus there's no reason to *find* the button with `.closest()` as what `$(this).closest(".YesBTN")` returns will be precisely the same as `$(this)` in the "YesBTN" handler anyway.

On the other hand, finding the corresponding "No" button *will* require looking up the DOM tree for a common parent and then looking back down the tree for the other button:

```
$(this).closest(".profielEditTD").find(".NoBTN").removeClass("NoYES");
```

It's not completely clear from the HTML in your question, but to find that input field I think you'd have to use its name:

```
$("input[name='intern']").val("yes");
```

for example.

Comment: Allright, so the addClass / removeCLass works now, still the value problem remains

Comment: @JeffreyvanZwam are you still trying to assign something to the `.value` property? That won't work; re-read the answer.

Comment: No, tried multiple lines, based on your example. All without success

Comment: @JeffreyvanZwam the relationshjp between the buttons and your input field is not clear from what you posted. Your use of the `.parent()` function is generally wrong; `.parent()` is for finding *parent* elements, and an `<input>` element is *never* a parent element.

Comment: Allright, thanks for that. I'll try something different. Thanks for helping me out with one part of my problem anyway!

Comment: Closest I could get was `$(this).parents().find('.inp-hid').val("yes");` Only problem: this changes all inputs and not just the one next to it...

Comment: @JeffreyvanZwam well like I said, the overall structure of your document isn't clear. The buttons are inside a `<td>` that's inside a `<tr>` with no identifying class or id value.